# PL/SQL wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P'

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a very simple situation in PL/SQL application. 
I create an array like so:

```
TYPE myArrayType IS TABLE OF myList%ROWTYPE;
myArray myArrayType;
```

myList is a cursor with 63 rows. Later in my code I try to loop trough my newly created array like so:

```
    htp.p('<h2>My data table</h2>');
    htp.p('<table>');

      for elem in 1 .. myArray.count loop
        htp.p('<tr>');
          htp.p('<td>');
            htp.p(' Data= '||myArray(elem)||' ');    //   <-- ERROR 
          htp.p('</td>');
        htp.p('</tr>');
      end loop;

    htp.p('</table>');
```

But I get an error 'wrong number or types of arguments', can someone please help a newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```
htp.p(' Data= '||myArray(elem)||' ');    //   <-- ERROR
```

You are trying to concatenate string with the record, therefore you are getting an error. To fix your problem you have to provide the column name existing in this record:

```
htp.p(' Data= '||myArray(elem).column_name||' ');
```